# Android Error : Connection getting reset after reading bufferedreader

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm using a method called `registerDevice()` in my android app
code to send and receive specific data which contains multiple lines. But I keep getting this error:

> W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

```
public void registerDevice(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                Socket s = new Socket(gateway, 1234);
                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                output.println("hello world\r\n");
                output.flush();
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = null;
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                }
                final String st = line.substring(5);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (st.trim().length() != 0)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),st,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                output.close();
                out.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

UPDATE: I changed the code to this:

```
                Socket s = new Socket(gateway, 1234);
                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                output.println("hello world\r\n");
                output.flush();
                final String st = input.readLine();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (st.trim().length() != 0)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"st",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                output.close();
                out.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I'm Still getting exceptions on the "final String st = input.readLine();" line. I am supposed to get a MAC address from the server and then the server closes the connection.I checked the server and there is nothing wrong with it, it closes the connection AFTER it sends me the MAC.

Comment: You are getting it at which line of code? after interacting with what peer code?

Comment: @user207421 at this line " while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) ", it happens when i want to call input.readline() for the second time

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the problem, it was the packet I was sending, I just changed outout.println() to output.write(), so now the server recognized my command and sent the data I needed which led to my input stream not being empty and avoiding exceptions.